# JSpinner textfield gets deactivated when setting JSpinnerModel

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want a JSpinner into which textfield only integers can be typed or numbers can be choosen with the Spinning Buttons.

Therefore I wrote two classes:

1) `NumberCodeFormatterFactory extends DefaultFormatterFactory` 
 2) `IntegerSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel`.

Now when I set the IntegerSpinnerModel into the JSpinner the textfield of the JSpinner gets deactivated, so no values can be typed into it anymore. But the Spinning Buttons work fine.

This is my IntegerSpinnerModel:

```
import javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class IntegerSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7145780527051124946L;

   int number = 0;
   int minimum = 0;
   int maximum = 0;

   public Object getValue()
   {
      return String.valueOf(number);
   }

  public void setValue(Object value)
   {
      if (value instanceof Integer)
      {
         int input = (int) value;
         if (minimum <= input && maximum >= input)
         {
            this.number = input;
            this.fireChangeEvent();
         }
     }

      if (value instanceof String)
      {
         try
         {
            int input = Integer.valueOf((String) value);
            if (minimum <= input && maximum >= input)
            {
               this.number = input;
               this.fireChangeEvent();
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {

         }
      }
   }

   public void setMinimum(int minimum)
   {
      this.minimum = minimum;
   }

  public void setMaximum(int maximum)
   {
      this.maximum = maximum;
   }

   private void fireChangeEvent()
   {
      for (ChangeListener l : super.getChangeListeners())
     {
         l.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
      }
   }

   public Object getNextValue()
   {
      int next = number + 1;
     if (minimum <= next && maximum >= next)
      {
         this.number = next;
         this.fireChangeEvent();
      }
      return String.valueOf(next);
   }

   public Object getPreviousValue()
   {
      int previous = number - 1;
      if (minimum <= previous && maximum >= previous)
      {
         this.number = previous;
          this.fireChangeEvent();
      }
      return String.valueOf(previous);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a custom SpinnerModel is set, then the JSpinner.DefaultEditor is invoked.
[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#model)

> JSpinner.DefaultEditor: Implements an uneditable component that displays the spinner's value.

Therefore JSpinner.DefaultEditor must be extended to make a "MyCustomEditor" and with

```
getTextField().setEditable(true);
```

the JFormattedTextField can be made editable.

Also the "MyCustomEditor" is the right place to add any FormatterFactory to the textfield.

Still, the user will be able to enter invalid text, even Objects into the textfield, that is how the JFormattedTextField was made. But with a custom FormatterFactory that provides a good custom "MyFormatter" extends AbstractFormatter any invalid Content entered by the user will never get to JSpinner.